# When do cron tasks begin to execute?

Tags: boot, cron, startup

Having read through the Wikipedia page on cron, it is unclear to me when cron begins to execute the tasks I have defined in the crontab file. Is it during the boot process - or even at the end of it - or later? I am sure that they are executed when I login into the system (Linux Mint 17.3), however what happens if I do not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tasks defined in the various `crontab` files are executed by `crond`, which is started during boot by your `init` (whether that's `sysvinit`, systemd or Upstart). `crond` processes tasks as soon as it starts, so you'll see `crontab`-defined tasks potentially start executing before the system has finished booting.

In any case `crond` will run tasks you've scheduled regardless of whether you're logged in or not. You can boot a system up without ever logging into it, and `crond` will still run the tasks that have been defined – this is typically the case on servers.

The [`crond(8)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/cron.8.html) manpage has all the details.